# Apex - Clear form when leaving page (also on redirect)

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

Currently, if I populate a form and leave the page, the form entries will still be present when I return to the form. Is it possible to prevent these entries from being saved?

The items' default values are populated using PS/SQL, but the content can be adjusted.

I tried creating a dynamic action to clear the items on 'Page Unload', but this didn't do anything. Is this the correct browser event, or did I simply get the implementation wrong?

---

**Update:** To provide a bit of context...

Pages:

1. Home
2. Form
3. DML Form (insert) - *I want any modifications to not be stored*

Page 3 can be accessed via Page 1 or Page 2.

If the user accesses the form via Page 2 (a different form), they will have selected a specific value and this is used to populate default values on Page 3 (via item and PL/SQL Function Body).

If the user accesses the form via Page 1, the same PL/SQL will run - this may result in Page 3 form items being empty (NULL default values).

HOWEVER, when the user edits Page 3 items (changing from default values), these values will persist when the user next accesses the form. How can I prevent this state from being captured?

Comment: Can you share some more info on the form page? What's it meant to do? How do you "return" to it?

Comment: @Tom I have updated the question with more context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to clear the cache of the page. This will clear the session state of the items on the page and thus result in items being empty once again.
You may need to add this clear on several locations. If you have used column links to access the page, buttons with redirects, branches, etc. [The apex URL has a part which states which pages have to be cleared](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03017), and you can generally define this clearing of a page cache declaratively.
[image: Link builder apex 5]

You can also create processes where you can define which page (or pages) has to be cleared. For example, if you always want the cache to be cleared when entering the page, no matter where you came from, you could add a process on the page doing just that.
[image: Process type apex 5]
Session state is ultimately what is causing this behavior: go to the page, change some things, page gets submitted for whatever reason and causes session state to be saved.
Usually, on DML forms generated through the wizard, the cache would only be cleared when using the "create" button coming from another location (usually the overlying report).

[Here is the (apex 5.0) documentation on session state and managing it.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept_ses_val.htm#HTMDB03012)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with something like this, but first you need to add jQuery to your page. I recommend using a content delivery network (CDN). You can edit the code to clear the value in your type of forms. I hope this could help you!

[jQuery CDN example](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body")
        .find("input").val("")
        .end()
        .find("select").val("-")
        .end()
        .find("textarea").val("");
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go. I'm assuming this will run before any of the PS/SQL that pre-populates the form with default values? - I don't know how introducing jQuery will interact/conflict with the underlying stuffs, e.g. I have seen `apex.jQuery(document).ready(function()` floating around the internet.

Comment: You can use `$.noConflict();`, but then you need to switch your **$** sign to **jQuery**. Example : `$.noConflict(); jQuery(document).ready(function() ...`

Comment: @PidgeyBAWK you don't need to "introduce" jquery on the page, and it does not have to conflict. Apex comes bundled with jQuery, and in 4.2 it uses jQuery version 1.7. You should not add another version unless you have a very specific use case. `apex.jQuery.ready()` functions just as well. However, you can simply use a dynamic action with "Page Load". Furthermore, this answer doesn't actually cover the apex usecase. This is not the way to "clear" your page as values will still reside in the session.

Comment: @Tom If this is not the correct approach for the use-case, could you recommend an approach to removing the form values from the session?

Comment: @PidgeyBAWK I added a comment on your question requesting some more details, right now I don't have enough info on what you're doing or trying to achieve.